# Можно ли вытащить Canvas c ImageView

Tags: android, java

Есть некая экранная форма (TextView, Spinner, Button и ImageView)

Добавляем Background в ImageView:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.stars);
ImageView  ll = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
BitmapDrawable tiledBackground = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(tiledBackground);
```

А можно ли получить Canvas c ImageView и рисовать на нем, при условии что работаем с классом, например public class ExampleClass extends **Activity**, а не с public class ExampleClass extends **View** , где есть функция onDraw(Canvas canvas) ?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку предполагается рисовать по холсту `ImageView`, разумно делать это в самом `ImageView`. То есть создать новый класс, унаследовавшись от `ImageView` и уже в нем рисовать в методе `onDraw()`. А самим классом манипулировать извне с помощью дополнительных публичных методов.

Либо сначала рисовать по холсту, а потому отрисовывать его методом [draw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)).